# Ralink RT3290 not working in Kali Linux 2020.3

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I recently **dual booted** **Kali Linux 2020.3**  ,kernel 5.8.0-kali2–amd64 , with **Windows 10** in UEFI on **HP Envy Touchsmart 4-1245tu**. In Kali the ethernet works fine but it shows “WiFi is disabled” in the Network Manager applet. The package firmware-misc-nonfree is installed which has rt3290.bin file. How do I get it to work?

**Part Number of Wireless card : 690020-005**

Official Specifications Link : https://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c03743544

Comment: Did you check for example the rfkill tool to see if it's toggled off and can be turned on?

Comment: rfkill says its hard blocked. So I used the wifi switch to turn that (hard block) off but still doesn’t work. It worked around 2 years back. Could it be the kernel that’s causing issues? Also nmcli wlan0 says “sw disabled”

Comment: Depending on the implementation, the hard block can also be sw controlled. Does `rfkill unblock all` unblock it?

Comment: Nope it doesn’t. Although sudo airmon-ng start wlan0 says it is possibly running in KVM. I installed on hard disk :(

Comment: I have no other idea. But you should state your exact computer model in case somone knows a specific issue about it. Hardware issues like this are usually not solved on UL SE because it involves a lot of exchanges, and the Q/A based system isn't suited.

Comment: Ok. I will try Live USBs from 2016.1 to 2018.4. During that time it worked. I think it probably is kernel issue.

Comment: I think I found out the problem. Windows does not shutdown completely but rather hibernates. It is seen during boot from Live mode of kali. How do I repair that?

Comment: @Pranav please edit your question to include all relevant details, so that htey are available "at a glance".

Comment: What all details?